# How to add a static library CppUTests to my project atmel studio

Tags: embedded, atmel, cpputest

I'm using Atmel Studio 6.1.2 SP2. I'm setting up CppUTest for our embedded system project.
I created a static CPP library for the CppUTest Framework which copiled successfuly after a small change. Now I'm including this library to a test project. A C++ application project.

[image]

The issue I'm facing now is that even though the intellisense is auto completing my include, that means that it sees where the library is, I get "No chuch file or directory" error when compiling.

In GccApplication1.cpp I have this:

```
#include <avr32/io.h>
#include <CommandLineTestRunner.h>

int main(int ac, const char** av)
{
    /* These checks are here to make sure assertions outside test runs don't crash */
    CHECK(true);
    LONGS_EQUAL(1, 1);

    return CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(ac, av);
}
```

And the error is that it can't find the CommandLineTestRunner.h. I tried with "" and <> but it doesn't see it.

Any ideas?
For more information. I'm following the steps from Atmel, here is the [tutorial](http://www.atmel.no/webdoc/atmelstudio/ch04s02s03s04.html):

Comment: The library itself appears to be added correctly, but is the library's path in the include list for the compilation?  I think including the library just gives the linker something to link with, you still need to add path information manually...

Comment: Hello Ross, Thanks, your suggestion helped moving the compilation forward. You may post it as answer, I check it as correct and we close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the library only tells the linker that the file is available to be linked with the rest of your object code.  What appears to be missing is telling the compiler where it can find the header files for the library.  If you add the library path to your include list you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The "No such file or directory" error is a preprocessor error.  It is telling you that the include file cannot be found in the include file path.  Your IDE will have a way to specify the include path.

If you are using make, then you will want to use the -I option.

If you are using CppUTest's MakeFileWorker.mk, you will want to add define an environment variable, CPPUTEST_HOME, that specifies the directory where you installed CppUTest.

I hope that helps.